# Select all fields from collection with related items in another collection using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have 2 `ICollection` objects which are returned from the database for reporting purposes, I am writing a LINQ query to join the two collections to get the desired result which would be a 'Merged' or 'Joined' collection.

I have tried the following but it returns two entity collections.

```
var result = (from c in PatientsCollection.Items
              join x in PatientDstData on c.EpisodeID equals x.EpisodeID into n
              select new { c, n })
             .ToList();

var result = (from c in PatientsCollection.Items
              join x in PatientDstData on c.EpisodeID equals x.EpisodeID into n
              select new { c.Name, n })
             .ToList();
```

The problem is that the `PatientsCollection` has over a 120 fields that should be in the report so I dont want to do the following:

```
select new { c.Name, c.Surname, c.Address,... }
```

How can I select all fields from the `PatientsCollection` plus the fields from the collection `PatientDstData`. They have a matching field : `EpisodeID`. Each row gets exported to a excel spreadsheet using EPPlus.

Comment: How will you export them with EPPlus without knowing the fieldnames? Does it automatically output the contents of classes using Reflection? Perhaps you need to consider an `ExpandoObject`?

Comment: EPPlus automatically outputs everything for you with the LoadFromCollection method using reflection. Have never used an ExpandoObject, will look into that. Sorry forgot to mention that the 2 collections are not the same type, they have different models as the data is in 2 different tables.

Comment: I have an answer that will flatten the class into a new anonymous type created at runtime, or into `ExpandoObject`s populated at runtime. There is a bit of extra code to create anonymous types - do you have a preference?

Comment: Also, your examples are using `GroupJoin` i.e. the type of `n` is `IEnumerable<PatientDstData>` - is it possible to have more than one `PatientDstData` for each patient, or did you mean to do an inner join?

Comment: I dont mind an extra bit of code. A patient can have many records in PatientDstData, some patients have more than 30 records for each occasion they had tests done, i think my join should be a left outer join.  Thanks for the help so far!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a left join query, you must have a second from clause:

```
var result = from i in PatientsCollection.Items
             join pdd in PatientDstData on i.EpisodeID equals pdd.EpisodeID into pddj
             from pdd in pddj
             select new { i, pdd };
```

Now, using the below methods, you can flatten the contents of result (I left off the `ToList` since the flatten process will handle that). The anonymous object created is a simpler version of the compiler created one: it has no methods, and uses public fields instead of properties (though I think I will write a full-blown anonymous object method since I've seen more questions about it lately).

```
var flatResult = result.FlattenToNewObjects().ToList();
```

Here are the methods needed:

```
public static class AnonymousExt {
    // convert a class containing members that are composite into a flattened class object
    // only flatten one level deep; do not flatten collections
    public static object FlattenToNewObject<T>(this T srcObject) {
        var oldMITs = typeof(T).GetMITs();
        var newType = oldMITs.FlattenedType();
        var newMIs = newType.GetPropertiesOrFields();

        return srcObject.CopyFlattened(oldMITs, newType, newMIs);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object> FlattenToNewObjects<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src) {
        var oldMITs = typeof(T).GetMITs();
        var newType = oldMITs.FlattenedType();
        var newMIs = newType.GetPropertiesOrFields();

        foreach (var srcObj in src)
            yield return srcObj.CopyFlattened(oldMITs, newType, newMIs);
    }

    class MemberInfoType {
        public MemberInfo mi;
        public Type mt;
        public bool IsSimpleOrEnumerable;
        public List<MemberInfo> subMIs;
    }

    static List<MemberInfoType> GetMITs(this Type t) =>
        t.GetPropertiesOrFields().Select(mi => new { mi = mi, mt = mi.GetMemberType() })
        .Select(mit => new { mit, IsSimpleOrEnumerable = mit.mt.IsSimple() || mit.mt.IsIEnumerable() })
        .Select(mitb => new MemberInfoType { mi = mitb.mit.mi, mt = mitb.mit.mt, IsSimpleOrEnumerable = mitb.IsSimpleOrEnumerable, subMIs = mitb.IsSimpleOrEnumerable ? null : mitb.mit.mt.GetPropertiesOrFields() })
        .ToList();

    static Type FlattenedType(this List<MemberInfoType> oldMITs) {
        var newTypeDict = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
        // add all simple/collection members
        foreach (var mit in oldMITs)
            if (mit.IsSimpleOrEnumerable)
                newTypeDict.Add(mit.mi.Name, mit.mt);

        // flatten remaining composite members
        foreach (var mit in oldMITs)
            if (!mit.IsSimpleOrEnumerable) {
                foreach (var subMI in mit.subMIs) {
                    // find unique name
                    var possibleName = subMI.Name;
                    var namect = 1;
                    while (newTypeDict.ContainsKey(possibleName)) {
                        possibleName = $"{subMI.Name}{namect}";
                        ++namect;
                    }
                    newTypeDict.Add(possibleName, subMI.GetMemberType());
                }
            }

        return FindOrMakeSimpleAnonType(newTypeDict);
    }

    static object CopyFlattened<T>(this T srcObject, List<MemberInfoType> oldMITs, Type newType, List<MemberInfo> newMIs) {
        var ansObj = Activator.CreateInstance(newType);
        var memberIdx = 0;
        foreach (var mit in oldMITs)
            if (mit.IsSimpleOrEnumerable)
                newMIs[memberIdx++].SetValue(ansObj, mit.mi.GetValue(srcObject));
        foreach (var mit in oldMITs)
            if (!mit.IsSimpleOrEnumerable) {
                var subObj = mit.mi.GetValue(srcObject);
                foreach (var subMI in mit.subMIs)
                    newMIs[memberIdx++].SetValue(ansObj, subMI.GetValue(subObj));
            }
        return ansObj;
    }

    // ***
    // *** Type Extensions
    // ***
    public static List<MemberInfo> GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
        t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToList();

    // ***
    // *** MemberInfo Extensions
    // ***
    public static Type GetMemberType(this MemberInfo member) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.FieldType;
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.PropertyType;
            case EventInfo mei:
                return mei.EventHandlerType;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be if type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or EventInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }

    public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.GetValue(srcObject);
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.GetValue(srcObject);
            case MethodInfo mi:
                return mi.Invoke(srcObject, null);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or MethodInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
    public static T GetValue<T>(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) => (T)member.GetValue(srcObject);

    public static void SetValue(this MemberInfo member, object destObject, object value) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                mfi.SetValue(destObject, value);
                break;
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                mpi.SetValue(destObject, value);
                break;
            case MethodInfo mi:
                mi.Invoke(destObject, new object[] { value });
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or MethodInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
    public static void SetValue<T>(this MemberInfo member, object destObject, T value) => member.SetValue(destObject, (object)value);

    // ***
    // *** Type Extensions
    // ***
    public static bool IsNullableType(this Type aType) =>
    // instantiated generic type only                
        aType.IsGenericType &&
        !aType.IsGenericTypeDefinition &&
        Object.ReferenceEquals(aType.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), typeof(Nullable<>));

    // Stack Overflow
    public static bool IsSimple(this Type type) =>
        type.IsNullableType() ? type.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsSimple()
                              : type.IsPrimitive ||
                                type.IsEnum ||
                                type.Equals(typeof(string)) ||
                                type.Equals(typeof(decimal)) ||
                                type.Equals(typeof(TimeSpan)) ||
                                type.Equals(typeof(DateTime));
    public static bool IsIEnumerable(this Type type) => typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type);

    // ***
    // *** Anonymous Type Extensions
    // ***
    private static readonly CustomAttributeBuilder CompilerGeneratedAttributeBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes), new object[0]);
    private static ModuleBuilder AnonTypeMB;
    private static int AssemCount = 25;

    // create a pseudo anonymous type (POCO) from an IDictionary of property names and types
    // using public fields instead of properties
    // no methods are defined on the type
    public static Type MakeSimpleAnonType(IDictionary<string, Type> objDict) {
        // find or create AssemblyBuilder for dynamic assembly
        if (AnonTypeMB == null) {
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName($"MyDynamicAssembly{AssemCount}");
            var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            AnonTypeMB = ab.DefineDynamicModule("MyDynamicModule");
        }
        // get a dynamic TypeBuilder
        var typeBuilder = AnonTypeMB.DefineType($"<>f__AnonymousType{AssemCount++}`{objDict.Keys.Count}", TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.AutoLayout | TypeAttributes.NotPublic | TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit);
        typeBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(CompilerGeneratedAttributeBuilder);

        // create generic parameters for every field
        string gtpName(string fieldName) => $"<{fieldName}>j__TPar";
        var gtpnames = objDict.Keys.Select(k => gtpName(k)).ToArray();
        var gtpbs = typeBuilder.DefineGenericParameters(gtpnames);
        var gtpN2Bs = gtpnames.Zip(gtpbs, (n, pb) => new { n, pb }).ToDictionary(g => g.n, g => g.pb);

        // add public fields to match the source object
        var fbs = new List<FieldBuilder>();
        foreach (var srcFieldName in objDict.Keys)
            fbs.Add(typeBuilder.DefineField(srcFieldName, gtpN2Bs[gtpName(srcFieldName)], FieldAttributes.Public));

        // Fix the generic class
        var fieldTypes = objDict.Values.ToArray();
        return typeBuilder.CreateType().MakeGenericType(fieldTypes);
    }

    static string MakeAnonymousTypeKey(IDictionary<string, Type> objDict) => objDict.Select(d => $"{d.Key}~{d.Value}").Join("|");

    public static Dictionary<string, Type> PrevAnonTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
    public static Type FindOrMakeSimpleAnonType(IDictionary<string, Type> objDict) {
        var wantedKey = MakeAnonymousTypeKey(objDict);
        if (!PrevAnonTypes.TryGetValue(wantedKey, out var newType)) {
            newType = MakeSimpleAnonType(objDict);
            PrevAnonTypes[wantedKey] = newType;
        }

        return newType;
    }

    // ***
    // *** IEnumerable Extensions
    // ***
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string sep) => String.Join(sep, strings);
}
```